# Nothing to be done for running snakefile

Tags: snakemake

My code is like this, I have set the rule all:

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("data/sam/{sample}.sam", sample=SAMPLE_NAMES)

rule trimmomatic:
    input:
        "data/samples/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "data/samples/{sample}.clean.fastq"
    shell:
        "trimmomatic SE -threads 5 -phred33 -trimlog trim.log {input} {output} LEADING:20 TRAILING:20 MINLEN:16"

rule hisat2:
    input:
        fa="data/genome.fa",
        fastq="data/samples/{sample}.clean.fastq"
    output:
        "data/sam/{sample}.sam"
    shell:
        "hisat2-build {input.fa} ./index/geneindex | hisat2 -x - -q samples/{inout.fastq} -S {output}"
```

but it still shows that :

> Nothing to be done.
>   I have try to find the way out. but useless. 
>   help!

Comment: could you confirm that your SAMPLE_NAMES list is defined in the real script, please

Comment: Assuming list `SAMPLE_NAMES` is not empty, it sounds like
target outfile `data/sam/{sample}.sam` already exists. You may have to delete that file and run the snakefile. Or force run it.

Comment: I have already set the SAMPLE_NAMES like this:   SAMPLE_NAMES = ["A","B","C"]

Comment: Although unrelated to your actual question, do you realise that hisat2 will build an index each time it performs an alignment; You might be better adding a separate rule to `hisat2-build` your index, set the output to be a temp() (or indeed, use the prebuilt indexes from the hisat2 website). You might also want to set your trimmomatic ouputs to be temp() as well, to reduce storing unimportant files.